# ActiveRecord: Unique by attribute

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to filter `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`s to be unique by parent id.

So, I'd like a list like this:

```
[#<Message id: 25, posted_by_id: 3, posted_at: "2014-10-30 06:02:47", parent_id: 20, content: "This is a comment", created_at: "2014-10-30 06:02:47", updated_at: "2014-10-30 06:02:47">,
   #<Message id: 23, posted_by_id: 3, posted_at: "2014-10-28 16:11:02", parent_id: 20, content: "This is another comment", created_at: "2014-10-28 16:11:02", updated_at: "2014-10-28 16:11:02">]}
```

to return this:

```
[#<Message id: 25, posted_by_id: 3, posted_at: "2014-10-30 06:02:47", parent_id: 20, content: "This is a comment", created_at: "2014-10-30 06:02:47", updated_at: "2014-10-30 06:02:47">]
```

I've tried various techniques including:

```
@messages.uniq(&:parent_id) # returns the same list (with duplicate parent_ids)

@messages.select(:parent_id).distinct # returns [#<Message id: nil, parent_id: 20>]
```

and `uniq_by` has been removed from Rails 4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
group(:parent_id)
```

It sounds to me like that is what you are after. This does return the first entry with the given parent_id. If you want the last entry you will have to reorder the result in a subquery and then use the group.

Answer (score 3):

For me in Rails 3.2 & Postgresql, Foo.group(:bar) works on simple queries but gives me an error if I have any where clauses on there, for instance

```
 irb> Message.where(receiver_id: 434).group(:sender_id)
 => PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "messages.id" must appear in the
    GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I ended up specifying an SQL 'DISTINCT ON' clause to select.  In a Message class I have the following scope:

```
 scope :latest_from_each_sender, -> { order("sender_id ASC, created_at DESC").select('DISTINCT ON ("sender_id") *') }
```

Usage:

```
 irb> Message.where(receiver_id: 434).latest_from_each_sender
```